# Checking if a root exists in a multidimensional polynomial

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polynomials, numerical-methods, roots

Say that we have an $n$ dimensional polynomial of degree $m$. Are there any methods to check whether a root exists when $x_k \in [a_k, b_k]$ other than directly attempting Newton's method to solve for one?

Again I am only trying to prove the existence of **at least one** root in the set of intervals.

Comment: How to deal with the one variable case?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to link this to a similar, recent question below which is not exactly a duplicate but leads, in my opinion, to the same answer: to use the Interval Arithmetic methods,

[Intervals and polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2813322/intervals-and-polynomials)